# Why doesn't `find` find these files

Tags: find

Consider:

```
$ find . -name *.css
./style.css
./view/css/style.css

$ ls view/css/
consultation.css  jquery.scombobox.min.css  page-content.css  style.css
```

**Why might `find` have missed the files in `view/css`?** This is on Ubuntu 15.10, an obscure Debian derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to be the problem has something to do with the shell interpreting your name expression as a glob. Try doing this:

```
$ find . -name \*.css
```

Comment: Yeah - however you want to protect the asterisk from being interpreted as a shell glob.

Answer (score 1):

Right at the bottom of the `find` manpage is the following gem:

```
NON-BUGS
   $ find . -name *.c -print
   find: paths must precede expression
   Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

   This  happens  because *.c has been expanded by the shell resulting in find actually receiving a
   command line like this:
```

So `*.css` was apparently expanded by Bash to `style.css` becasue that file exists in the current directory. **Always escape `*` asterisks in `find`!**

```
$ find . -name \*.css
./style.css
./view/css/consultation.css
./view/css/lib/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css
./view/css/lib/normalize.min.css
./view/css/lib/swiper.min.css
./view/css/style.css
./view/css/jquery.scombobox.min.css
./view/css/page-content.css
```